# Wordpress theme with multiple color schemes

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am building a WP theme and want to implement multiple color schemes. I looked through different free and premium themes and found out that this feature is developed different ways there and here. What is the best practice to make multiple color schemes support in a theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually load a different style sheet for each color, based on a wordpress setting or, to lighten the load on the database, i just copy the \color_x.css over the \style.css.